# Jackson + Scala: No deserializer found for case class

Tags: scala, jackson

I am relatively new to Scala and using Jackson, I am getting below error for following `case class`:

```scala
case class Result(label: String,  resultDate: Option[Date] = None)
```

> Resolved[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: No deserializer for document type 'result' found; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No deserializer for document type 'result' found
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 209] (through reference chain: com.project["document"])]

Comment: Any particular reason why you need to use Jackson? It's usually better to use a Scala library, such as zio-json or circe.

Comment: Jackson is part of requirement :(

Comment: @Matthias sounds like an opinion rather than a fact. Jackson do work in Scala. Not natively of course.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide Jackson a way to deserialize this type: Jackson (core) doesn't know Scala and especially `case class` since it's originally a Java library.

You can add [Jackson Scala Module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) for automatic support of Scala types.